# Making /tmp and /home be on the same partition

Tags: rhel, mount, fstab

An application running under RHEL 7.x wasn't able to execute atomic file movement from `/tmp` to `/home`. It turned out they are located on different partitions

```
# df -h /tmp/
/dev/mapper/rhel-tmp   3,9G          17M  3,6G            1% /tmp

# df -h /home/
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   7,3G         1,9G  5,1G           28% /
```

Am I right in thinking that if I remove the entry for `/tmp` from `/etc/fstab` and reboot the system the `/tmp` will be on `/dev/mapper/rhel-root` ?

This is a corporate RHEL virtual machine, so it's highly desired that the steps lead to the goal after the first attempt. Unfortunately I don't have RHEL installed and there don't seem to be any Docker images to experiment with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right.
After removal of corresponding entry in `/etc/fstab`
`/tmp` moved to `/dev/mapper/rhel-root`

Comment: `/dev/mapper/rhel-tmp` is now unused and you are wasting 3,6G of space, but this is not a big deal. Just thought I should let you know.

Comment: @GMaster yes. But it's a temporary solution to make the app work as expected. I've notified system administrators that they should place /tmp and /home on the same partition when they recreate the virtual machine.

Comment: Note that you should make sure the permissions of the newly-revealed `/tmp` directory on the root filesystem are `drwxrwxrwt`(the `t` at the end is the important part - fix with `chmod 1777 /tmp` if necessary) and if SELinux is in use, also run `restorecon -R -v /tmp` to make sure SELinux labeling of the directory is correct.

Comment: @GMaster fortunately, this is LVM so it’s easy to recover.

Comment: @jsbillings True. And since after extending the additional recovered space from `/tmp`, the filesystem has to be extended, it is a totally safe operation which can be done on-line (no unmounting or playing with `fdisk`/`parted`)